npm MYSQL often in timeout
I am using mysql Pool to handle DB connections of my Nodejs server. Node server is used by a WebApp. Node server is deployed under Heroku, MySql DB is hosted by Google SQL.
A couple of times each day, everything stucks and I have to restart my server. I discovered that the problem is that at a certain point, all the DB requests go in timeout.
This is how I init DB connections.

global.pool;

function initPool()  // called on Server starts
{
  const mysql = require("mysql"); // mysql@2.18.1
  pool = mysql.createPool({
                           connectionLimit : 30,
                           host     : '******',
                           port     : '******',
                           user     : '******',
                           password : '******',
                           database : '******',
                           waitForConnections : true   // If true, the pool will queue the connection request and call it when one becomes available. 
                          }); 

    pool.on('acquire', function (connection) {
      console.log('[mysql] Connection %d acquired', connection.threadId);
    });     

    pool.on('connection', function (connection) {
      console.log('[mysql] Connection %d connected', connection.threadId);   
    });     

    pool.on('enqueue', function () {
      console.log('[mysql] enqueue. waiting for available connection slot');
    });

    pool.on('release', function (connection) {
      console.log('[mysql] Connection %d released', connection.threadId);
    });                        
    pool.on('error', function (err) {
      console.error(err);
}); 
}

This is how I ask a simple query
static getSomething(condition)
{
  var deferred = Q.defer();
   var query = ` 
                  SELECT *
                  FROM table
                  WHERE field = "${condition}";        
                `;
   pool.query(query, function(error, results, fields)
     {
       if(error) 
         {
          deferred.reject(error);
          return;
         }
       deferred.resolve(results);
     });
  return deferred.promise;         
}

Is there something wrong that I'm missing? Why I have to restart everything each day? Should I manage in a different way the opening/closing of the DB connection?

Does Heroku keep your app running when it's not serving requests?

yes, app is reachable. it just goes in timeout for requests involving query on the DB

check if you have a "readme" table (or some other non-familiar table) in your db

i havent touched Heroku for years, and at first thought it's because of their 18 hours sleep limit, but they've apparently gotten rid of their free tier. check out some alternatives

How are you allowlisting your Heroku app? I assume you're connecting over public IP. If so you need to either use the Cloud SQL Proxy or allowlist a CIDR range, but I'm not sure Heroku advertises those ranges. This might be useful if you go the Proxy route: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/emartech/heroku-buildpack-cloud-sql-proxy

I had to whitelist 0.0.0.0 unfortunately with heroku..

and it's true, there is no more sleep limit, it's not a free tier
